# A Option to creating shortcuts for swing application

Tags: java, swing, vbscript, wsh

We have a big Java Swing application and with it comes a jar called CreateShortcut that creates a vbscript .wsf who does the job of creating the shortcuts for the system and also put it on the on the start menu and runs it with

```
Runtime.getRuntime()
      .exec((new StringBuilder("cmd /c \"")).append(getFileWsf()).append("\"").toString())
      .waitFor();
```

But it always ask for permission to run it from the operational system, and that is scaring a lot of clients.

I would like to know if there's a way of doing it without asking for the permission with the .wsf or maybe just do it on the jar itself with java. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you realize that using a `StringBuilder` like that is a complete waste of time in that context?  Simple string concatenation (with `+`) will be just as fast.

Comment: I prefer an .exe launcher that starts the application. I'm pretty happy with winrun4j for that purpose

Comment: Yes I do, and I'll change it but that is not my code, that is from the legacy jar they are using to do it, I'm helping out and copy and pasted here... it works anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is what I was looking for:

```
http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/
```